# Como acionar função periodicamente para atualizar dados em cada instância da aplicação Angular 5^?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Eu preciso fazer com que uma lista de dados seja atualizada a cada 5/10 minutos, esses dados no qual é trazido de uma API Spring Boot com armazenamento no MySQL, através de uma requisição feita pelo Angular. Eu gostaria de saber alguma maneira de ficar repetindo essa requisição e assim atualizando os dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [rx-polling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-polling), com ela você consegue fazer requisições periódicas definindo um intervalo.

Segue um exemplo:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // Não se esqueça de importar adequadamente :)
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let dado of dados">{{dado.meuDado}}</li>
      </ul>

      `
})

export class MyApp {
  private dados = [];
  observableDados: any;      

  constructor(http: Http) {
   this.observableDados = Observable.interval(5000) // Intervalo de polling (5 segundos nesse caso)
    .switchMap(() => http.get('http://minhaapirest.com/dados/')).map((data) => data.json()) // Requisição para sua API
        .subscribe((data) => {
           this.dados = data; 
           console.log(data); // Log para demonstração :)
        });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.observableDados.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu apenas fiz uma pequena mudança referente ao serviço utilizado. Utilizei o module HttpClient e também funcionou.

Comment: Esse Observable.interval() é boa prática? Existe algum problema em utilizar? Como por exemplo desempenho?

Comment: É um recurso da biblioteca, em geral funciona como uma thread. Em relação a performance, acho que depende muito da operação que você executa, por exemplo, você esta consultando uma URL com retorno de 50MB, a cada 1 segundo, vai ser pesado (não que impacte a performance, as vezes não :) ), mas vai de de medir o custo das operações executadas. Deixe para se preocupar com performance quando você de fato tiver problemas de performance

Comment: Uma última dúvida, vamos supor que eu tenha um simples chat (apenas textos) e gostaria de deixá-lo em tempo real (não precisa ser exatamente em realtime), eu poderia utilizar essa mesma biblioteca para ficar buscando atualizações das mensagens pela api?

Comment: Funcionar funciona, mas nesse cenário o ideal seria você utilizar websockets, como a lib [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) por exemplo